# Override JSP hook issue when deploying to Weblogic?

Tags: weblogic-10.x, liferay-6

I have an interesting issue which appears to be environment related. 
This works 100% fine using TOMCAT7 but doesn't work with WEBLOGIC 10.x

Have configured the following so that it overrides my JSP (liferay-hook.xml):

```
<hook>
    <custom-jsp-dir>/META-INF/custom_jsps</custom-jsp-dir>
    <custom-jsp-global>true</custom-jsp-global>
</hook>
```

The hook JSP file exists in the following project location:

```
docroot/META-INF/custom_jsps/html/portlet/login/login.jsp
```

Confirmed by looking at the exploded WAR files in WEBLOGIC that the hook portlet has the right content, on my server it was located here and visually checked the file:

```
tmp/_WL_user/xxxMYPROJECTxxx/xxxxx/war/META-INF/custom_jsps/html/portlet/login/login.jsp
```

*So far - looks good!*

Confirmed that **before** deploying the hook portlet that only the following file exists (with old login):

```
tmp/_WL_user/liferay-portal-6/xxxxx/war/html/portlet/login/login.jsp
```

*Again - looks good!*

Now this is where it gets interesting, confirmed that **after** deploying the hook portlet the following files exist:

```
tmp/_WL_user/liferay-portal-6/xxxxx/war/html/portlet/login/login.jsp
tmp/_WL_user/liferay-portal-6/xxxxx/war/html/portlet/login/login.portal.jsp
```

**PROBLEM:** Both files are the OLD COPY, for some reason the login.jsp does NOT contain the hook copy as I would expect.  Is this a defect or is there something special that has to be done to make it work in Weblogic10?